# Callback for removing a device file

Tags: linux, solaris, device-driver

Is there in any call back in linux and solaris device driver which will be called when the device file is removed from the system? Example if a volume is deleted by the volume manager, it deletes the block and char device interface for that device. Is there any callback in linux and solaris like open,close,strategy call which will be called when the deletion of block/char device is done?

Answer (score 1):

Device files are much the same as any other file, so you should be able to use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to watch for them appearing and/or disappearing.